# How to load dynamic JS code in DOM structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML with JS element that I need to load on runtime.

These are some example files to illustrate the functionality I'm looking for.

**File 1: index.html**

```
<div id="mydiv"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("GET","script.php",false);
   xmlhttp.send();
   var text=xmlhttp.responseText;
   var elem=document.getElementById("mydiv")
   elem.innerHTML=text
   func() 
</script>
```

**File 2: script.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function func(){
       alert("func")
   }
</script>
```

**ERROR returned by browser:**

> Inline script thread
>  Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined
>   variable: func Error thrown at line 20, column 0 in
>   localhost/my_project/:
>       func()

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` does not execute script elements in the html.

Try this:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","script.php",false);
xmlhttp.send();
var text=xmlhttp.responseText;

var root = document.createElement("div");
root.innerHTML = text;
var scripts = root.getElementsByTagName("script");

for( var i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i ) {
    var code = scripts[i].innerText || scripts[i].textContent || scripts[i].innerHTML || "";
    eval(code);
}

func();
```